# Scaling images in AS3 without losing quality

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm currently working on a flash project which allows users to upload an image to print out shirts. To position the image I currently scale the size of the image to 1/7 or 1/5, but the image pixelates and loses quality.

Is there any way to make the image smoother even though it's scaled down a lot?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

All image classes that I can think of have a `smooth` property. For sure, `Bitmap`, `Image`, and `BitmapImage` do. If you're using a `Loader`, you need to grab the raw `Bitmap` by accessing `Loader.content`. Set `smooth = true` and it should do exactly what you are looking for.

Keep in mind that the smoothing algorithm isn't overly fast and, if done on a large scale, can cause slow downs.

Comment: And be careful trying to do this with images on other domains etc:  `content` Throws: SecurityError — The loaded SWF file or image file belongs to a security sandbox to which you do not have access. For a loaded SWF file, you can avoid this situation by having the file call the Security.allowDomain() method or by having the loading file specify a loaderContext parameter with its securityDomain property set to SecurityDomain.currentDomain when you call the load() or loadBytes() method.